# Image is twitched when it's resized on hover with css transitions in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I have an image link. On hover the image is zoomed smoothly with help of css transitions. When an image is started/ended to be zoomed it's twitched. Does anybody have some advices how to remove this twitching?

In FF everything is OK.

```
<a href="#"><img src="image.jpg"></a>

a img {
    ...
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    transition: all .2s;
}

a:hover img {
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

[Sample in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kUKsm/2/)

Comment: I test in on windows maybe it affects. Could you test it in FF? In my case, I have a great difference.

Comment: My Chrome version is 24.0.1312.57 m